# WooCommerce Pinpoint Booking System plugin Dynamic prices

Tags: plugins, woocommerce, calendar, cart, checkout

i am using the plugin Pinpoint Booking System, the customer wants that bookings for a specific service have dynamic prices. 1 room = 200€ per night, 2 rooms = 350€ and 3 rooms (the maximum) = 450€. With the hook below i can change the price for that service but i don't know where to get the number of room and the stay starting and ending dates (to know how many days and then multiply it by the price).

```
add_action(‘woocommerce_before_calculate_totals’, ‘set_custom_price’);

function set_custom_price($cart_obj) {
  foreach ($cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[‘product_id’] == 3735) {
      $value[‘data’]->set_price(9.90);
      $new_price = $value[‘data’]->get_price();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

It doesn't seem to be useful, maybe what i need is in another variable:


array(12) { ["dopbsp_token"]=> string(64) "QkkHNJDd2HFU322bBx6qrTmJFnI9Qhtc7FWZ6FPgQ859QAn2unwF1O8SvphFGkAJ" ["key"]=> string(32) "cc1412ab620bfd85ea712f1f7fbee174" ["product_id"]=> int(3735) ["variation_id"]=> int(0) ["variation"]=> array(0) { } ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["line_tax_data"]=> array(2) { ["subtotal"]=> array(0) { } ["total"]=> array(0) { } } ["line_subtotal"]=> float(9.9) ["line_subtotal_tax"]=> int(0) ["line_total"]=> float(9.9) ["line_tax"]=> int(0)

Comment: ["data"]=> object(WC_Product_Simple)#9295 (13) { ["object_type":protected]=> string(7) "product" ["post_type":protected]=> string(7) "product" ["cache_group":protected]=> string(8) "products" ["data":protected]=> array(48) { ["name"]=> string(42) "Séjours dégustation vin" ["slug"]=> string(22) "sejours-gastronomiques" ["date_created"]=> object(WC_DateTime)#9313 (4) { ["utc_offset":protected]=> int(0) ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-01-03 09:20:26.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00" }

Comment: ["date_modified"]=> object(WC_DateTime)#9312 (4) { ["utc_offset":protected]=> int(0) ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-03-06 16:50:43.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00" } ["status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["featured"]=> bool(false) ["catalog_visibility"]=> string(7) "visible" ["description"]=> string(1823) "

Comment: So nothing useful is passed to cart item, which can help you to get what you need… Sorry, It's not really possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. If someone need it, you have to check the table dopbsp_woocommerce in your Wordpress database . It contains the token of the reservation, you can compare it to the token contained in $value["dopbsp_token"]. Then you can get the datas of the reservation in the "data" column of the same table. Use json_decode to read the informations contained in it